# Common interface for two Flutter plugins

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have two Android specific Flutter plugins. They are for two custom devices to access the same hardware with different platform specific SDKs.

I have successfully implemented both as Flutter plugins. I want use these in Flutter application and use the plugin based on the device.

I have created a common abstract class to expose same API but the flutter plugin class has all static methods which doesn't allows to implement a common interface.

How can we expose a common dart implement from a plugin and use it interchangeably.

For an example let say we have this abstract class as the common interface,

```dart
abstract class Pluggable{
   void plug();
}
```

The plugin class which is generated by Flutter create is,

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyPlugin {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('my_plugin');

  static Future<String?> get platformVersion async {
    final String? version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }

  static Future<void> plug() async {
    await _channel
        .invokeMethod('plug');
  }

}
```

The way of Flutter plugins to have static methods which can not be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your flutter plugin class has abstract methods. There are many ways to do this, from using a proper dependency injection framework to have the right type injected, to using a Provider or other InheritedWidget wrapper to hold the instance of the right plugin class and expose it in a common way.

However, the simplest way is to use a Singleton - assuming that this is something that that gets instantiated right at the beginning of the app running and is used throughout.

The way I'd recommend is to add a static initializer to your singleton. See the example below.

```dart
// this declares the abstract class.
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
  static void initializeWith(MyAbstractClass instance) {
    _instance = instance;
  }

  // this could introduce a potential bug if you don't initialize
  // or try to do it multiple times, so make sure you do that
  // properly exactly once.
  static late final MyAbstractClass _instance;
  static MyAbstractClass get instance => _instance;

  // methods to show how this works
  void method1();
  void method2();
  
  // an example of how to call directly from the class
  static void doMethod1() => _instance.method1();
}

// one simple implementation
class MyClass1 implements MyAbstractClass {
  @override
  void method1() => print(1);
  @override
  void method2() => print(2);
}

// another simple implementation
class MyClass2 implements MyAbstractClass {
  @override
  void method1() => print("a");
  @override
  void method2() => print("b");
}

// and in practice, you simply have to initialize and then
// use however you'd like.
void main() {
//   MyAbstractClass.initializeWith(MyClass1());
//   MyAbstractClass.doMethod1();
//   MyAbstractClass.instance.method2();
  
  MyAbstractClass.initializeWith(MyClass2());
  MyAbstractClass.doMethod1();
  MyAbstractClass.instance.method2(); 
}
```

You'd have to convert all of your static methods to members but that should be as simple as removing any static references and removing the static keywords.

Comment: add example to the question